Is there a commonly used expression for adjusting a training or form of support to a person's specific situation and needs?
In German, there is an expression that's commonly used to convey that a kind of support (i.e. job trainings but also other kinds of educational programs or things like psychological support programs) are tailored to a person's individual situation / background / experience: "To pick someone up from where they are standing". So, you look at where this person is at exactly and then "pick them up" from there. Is there something similar in English or what would be a good way to express this?

I think you'd just use an adjective like personalized/customized/custom/tailor-made. Nothing more specific or idiomatic.

In social work and psychological  support contexts, one could speak, informally, of the need to understand "where a person is coming from".    The phrase has a 1960s-era pop-psychology "vibe".  It refers to their lived experience, their outlook  on life combined with their particular life situation.

I'm curious -- what is the German expression?

By person, you mean  young person, right? Not adults?

@TonyK "Jemanden dort abholen, wo er/sie steht."

@Lambie Any person, adults or young people, regardless of age.

@snowlatte A personalized study program or plan. Or individualized. That said, these plans/programs are not generally for adults and I fail to see how they could be for adults in Germany either unless you are more specific.

OP's query:

Is there a commonly used expression for adjusting a training or form of support to a person's specific situation and needs?

One common way to express this idea is by using the verb "tailor," similar to how a tailor customizes a suit to fit a person.

1. tailor meaning.
verb.
past tense: tailored;
to make or design something for a particular person or purpose.
.
For example:

"Programs tailored to the needs of specific groups.".
.


customize.
verb.
gerund or present participle: customizing.
modify (something) to suit a particular individual or task.


"the software can be customized to the developing needs of your students"


This conveys the idea of customizing or adapting something to meet the unique requirements of a person or group.

The word "customize" would be appropriate also. You used it to describe "tailor," but it could also be used in place of "tailor."

@swmcdonnell Noted. I edited and added

"Meet someone (or "people") where they are (or "where they're at")" is almost exactly what you describe. While it doesn't say "support/help/teach", those are often the contexts in which it's used.

Thank you! I didn't know you could use the phrase like this, this is also very helpful :)

It's not a training program.

Unfortunately there's no one English word that conveys all that (as is often the case with German!). There is definitely a common vocabulary around this idea, though. One word that's common in educational or workplace discussion of meeting needs is accommodation, often used as a countable noun, like "The teacher implemented specific accommodations to address the student's dyslexia." (The word "intervention" is often used similarly in educational settings, though not elsewhere.) The notion of tailoring accommodations to a person's unique strengths and challenges would simply be conveyed by adding adjectives like "personalized" or "individual."

But there are phrases.

individualized education program, AmE
explanation
individualized or individual or personal education plan, BrE
UK
When kids struggle in school, you may hear the term IEP. What is an IEP? IEP is an acronym that stands for Individualized Education Program. Some people may refer to it as an Individualized Education Plan.

The purpose of an IEP An IEP is more than just a written legal
document (or “plan”). It’s a map that lays out the program of special
education instruction, supports, and services kids need to make
progress and thrive in school.**

IEP
In both, aka IEP.
vocational IEP

And as far as transition IEP goals, I find a lot of copying and pasting of meaningless goals into IEPs. Transition time is the most
important time for your student. Vocational IEP goals are one small
part of this.

A personalized study plan:

Six Steps to Create a Personalized and Effective Study Plan
What is
a study plan?


A study plan is an organized schedule that incorporates
your academic, professional, social, and personal commitments. Study
plans help you prioritize your tasks and budget your time to achieve
them.

personalized study plan
Individually Designed Education for Adult Learners (IDEAL)
The Individually Designed Education for Adult Learners Program (IDEAL) provides adult students an alternative experience to the traditional classroom setting. The IDEAL Program can meet the needs of students whose busy lifestyles or geographic location prohibit attending classes in an on-ground structured environment.
IDEAL
There are many ways to say this in English, take one term like personalized or individual and put it with study plan or program.

The sources you used seem to indicate that this is used for kids and also for specific cognitive disabilities.

@CaveJohnson Students who need extra help and support in school may be eligible for special education services in the form of an individualized education program (IEP). This program is offered free of charge to families of kids in public schools and outlines the goals and any support services that may be needed for a child to succeed in school. First LINK.

Sure, but still, it seems to be used for kids. This question asks for something that can be used for job training.

@CaveJohnson An individualized or individual or personal study plan is not just for kids.
